# Lebesgue nonmeasurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Using the continuum hypothesis, prove that there exists a Lebesgue nonmeasurable subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $E$ intersects every horizontal or vertical line in exactly one point.

Comment: This question is an exercise of Bruckner Real Analysis....p.178 no.14

Comment: There is a construction due to Sierspinski which you can find in Rudin, page 143. Let $j:[0,1]\to W$ be a bijection with $W$ well-ordered such that $j(x)$ has only countably many predecessors, for $x\in[0,1]$. Take $E$ to be the points $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$ such that $j(x)< j(y)$. To see non-measurability, check Fubini's theorem for its characteristic function.